# Why does my quicksort function in Python not work?

Tags: python

Here is my code:

```
def quicksort(arr):
    if len(arr) > 1:
        left = []
        right = []

        for i in range(1, len(arr)):
            if arr[i] < arr[0]:
                left.append(arr[i])
            else:
                right.append(arr[i])

        quicksort(left)
        quicksort(right)

        arr = left + [arr[0]] + right
```

It worked before, however I tried to simplify the code a bit by not returning `arr` but rather changing it in the function. Now it does not work anymore. Any reasons why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a scoping problem. In Python, as soon as you use the assignment "=" operator, it will assume that you no longer want to have anything to do with the original object in question.

Lets say arr originally had a reference of 361 (simplified) when it entered the function. Now if you changed a single element of the object, it's reference in memory would still be 361, hence the element would be changed in the original object. But your line `arr = left + [arr[0]] + right` now creates the local variable arr, which inside the function would have a reference of lets say 366. Now, any changes made to this variable do not transfer to the original arr, reference 361.

Because you no longer return this variable, no change can be made to the original object.

Comment: That sucks... I ended up using `clear(arr)` and adding each element to arr. It's no way as simple as my original function but it works.

Answer (score 3):

When you run this line of code:

```
arr = left + [arr[0]] + right
```

You're rebinding the name `arr` to a *local* value, and the connection to the original argument is lost.

Answer (score 0):

```
arr = left + [arr[0]] + right
```

This line creating a new list `arr` in the local scope. That's why the outer `arr` is not getting modified.

You need to find a way where `arr` won't be redeclared or get rebounded again, here is an example :

```
 def quicksort(arr):
    if len(arr) > 1:
        left = []
        right = []

        for i in range(1, len(arr)):
            if arr[i] < arr[0]:
                left.append(arr[i])
            else:
                right.append(arr[i])

        quicksort(left)
        quicksort(right)
        right = [arr[0]] + right
        arr.clear()
        arr.extend(*[left + right])
```